# Why does MySQL sometimes add a leading zero for BINARY column, and how do I make it stop?

Tags: mysql, binary, leading-zero

I have a BINARY(255) column in a MySQL database, and I need it to be able to store binary data exactly as I put it in.

If I run the query (UPDATE table SET bindata = 0xffff WHERE id = 1), the data appears with a leading zero, (0ffff0000).  However, if I add enough characters after the 0x (102, apparently?) the leading zero disappears and the inserted value shows up correctly.

Why does this happen, and how do I make it stop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mysql documentation on [hexadecimal literals](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/hexadecimal-literals.html) says:

> Values written using `0xval` notation that contain an odd number of digits are treated as having an extra leading 0. For example, `0xaaa` is interpreted as `0x0aaa`.

Mysql also supports the `X'val'` notation, but that one raises a syntax error if the literal has odd number of digits.

The reason for this restriction is simple:

> By default, a hexadecimal literal is a binary string, where each pair of hexadecimal digits represents a character.

I'm not aware any method to overcome this restriction. You may want to right pad the digits with a 0 if you have odd number of digits.

Comment: Hm...so what is the most "natural" means of inserting data into a binary column?  I've tried hexidecimal and base64 - should I be using base32 instead?

Comment: @IndigoFenix I'm sorry, but I do not understand your question.

Comment: I can insert hex into MySQL using 0x(hex value).  Is there a similar way to insert base32 values in, so that the input and output are predictable?

Comment: I think you are mixing up strings and numbers. The binary field is for storing text, not numbers. Base64 is also a way of encoding text, not to represent numbers.